# Sort array by other one - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Ive got 2 arrays, first one contains values of objects, and second one contains their IDs.

In this form:

```
$values[0] applies to $ids[0]
$values[1] applies to $ids[1]
```

I need to sort first array (using sort() ) from lowest to highest (values are ints) - That's not problem.
Problem is, that When I sort array with values, I will lost ID of that value.

My question is: How to make that

```
If $values[0] turns to $values[5], automatically turn $ids[0] to $ids[5]
```

Thanks

Update:

Content of $values and $ids:

```
$values[0] = 1.5;
$values[1] = 2.4;
$values[2] = 15.7;
$values[3] = 11.7;
$values[4] = 4.8;
$values[5] = 0.4;

$ids[0] = 1;
$ids[1] = 2;
$ids[2] = 3;
$ids[3] = 4;
$ids[4] = 5;
$ids[5] = 6;
```

Comment: Add the contents of `$values` and `$ids` to your question.

Comment: This makes no sense. Couldn't you just show "here are two arrays that go in, and this should come you".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the arrays first, then sort by key:

```
$newArr = array_combine($ids, $values);
ksort($newArr);
```

Comment: Note I just updated the code, use [`ksort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort by key as bfrohs suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

### Example

```
<?php
$ids = array(2, 1, 3); // IDs
$values = array(a, b, c); // Values
$array = array_combine($ids, $values); // Combine arrays as ID => Value
ksort($arrays); // Sort new array
print_r($array); // Echo array
```

### Output

```
Array
(
 1 => b,
 2 => a,
 3 => c,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code below... have not tested it ... but it must work.... Easy to understand..

```
<?php
$count = count($values);
for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
   if($i == 0)
   {
      $sort1 = $values[$i];
      $sort2 = $ids[$i];
      $temp = 0;
   }
   if($sort1 > $values[$i])
   {
      $sort1 = $values[$i];
      $sort2 = $ids[$i];

      $temp_val = $values[$temp];
      $temp_id = $ids[$temp];

      $values['temp'] = $values[$i];
      $ids['temp'] = $ids[$i];

      $temp = $i;

      $values[$i] = $temp_val;
      $ids[$i] = $temp_id;  

   }
}
?>
```